# JAR file not working but project running locally

Tags: java, spring, jar, executable-jar

Project running locally but when I try to run JAR file, it's failed. I exctracted JAR file to check test/b2b-policy.xml file path but it's there too.

```
Nov 29, 2022 11:17:33 AM org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory createApplicationContext
WARNING: Initial attempt to create application context was unsuccessful.
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [test/b2b-policy.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/2003-02-11.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:402)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.internalLoadBeanDefinitions(ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.access$000(ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader$1.run(ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:139)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader$1.run(ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:137)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ControlledValidationXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(BusApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext$1.run(BusApplicationContext.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext$1.run(BusApplicationContext.java:105)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext.<init>(BusApplicationContext.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createApplicationContext(SpringBusFactory.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:124)
    at dk.beboerparkering.integration.dmr.impl.agent.GetVehicleRegistrationAgent.getBindingProvider(GetVehicleRegistrationAgent.java:83)
    at dk.beboerparkering.integration.dmr.impl.agent.GetVehicleRegistrationAgent.execute(GetVehicleRegistrationAgent.java:58)
    at dk.beboerparkering.integration.dmr.facade.client.DmrClient.doVehicleRegistrationRequest(DmrClient.java:20)
    at dk.beboerparkering.integration.dmr.facade.client.DmrClient.main(DmrClient.java:58)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/2003-02-11.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1013)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:640)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:696)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2226)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:2128)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1049)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:1166)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:652)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2710)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.getGlobalElementDecl(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1639)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SubstitutionGroupHandler.getMatchingElemDecl(SubstitutionGroupHandler.java:78)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.models.XSDFACM.oneTransition(XSDFACM.java:302)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1934)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2725)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.TunedDocumentLoader.loadDocument(TunedDocumentLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 26 more
```

I tried to run JAR file using java -jar jarfilename.jar but I got errors. When I running the project locally, it's working and running. Here is b2b-policy.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 
  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.
-->
        <!--
        KN: removed from bean
        xmlns:wsrm-mgmt="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/rm/manager"
        xmlns:wsrm-policy="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy"-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
       xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xmlns:wsrm-mgmt="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/rm/manager"
       xmlns:wsrm-policy="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://cxf.apache.org/core
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">
    <import resource="META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>

    <!-- Handle secure / TLS Transport
     The keystore client-truststore.jks contains the SSL cert. for the test system
     as a trusted certificate.
     For more information please see:
     http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html
     -->
    <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <!-- Set timeout to 3 minutes -->
        <http:client Connection="Keep-Alive"
                     MaxRetransmits="1"
                     AllowChunking="false"
                     ConnectionTimeout="180000"/>
        <http:tlsClientParameters>
            <!-- https://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html -->
            
            <!-- Keystore path on Disk, this seems to work while integrating with WebAdmin  -->
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="ABC123">
                <sec:keyStore file="keystore/client-truststore.jks"
                              password="ABC123" type="JKS"/>
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore file="keystore/client-truststore.jks"
                              password="ABC123" type="JKS"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <!-- The following is just sample configuration.
                 The unix command nmap will list the currently support ciphers, e.g.:
                 nmap -script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <FQDN>
                -->
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
        </http:tlsClientParameters>
    </http:conduit>

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <!--<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>-->
            <!-- Configure WS-Security for RESPONSE -->
            <bean id="ResponseWSPolicyFulfillment" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="dk.beboerparkering.integration.dmr.impl.agent.UTPasswordCallback"/>
                        <!-- Signature Configuration -->
                        <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="etc/Client_Encrypt.properties"/>
                        <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
                        <entry key="signatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <!-- Configure WS-Security for REQUEST -->
            <bean id="RequestWSPolicyFulfillment" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
                        <!-- SKAT: Options =
                             - test
                             - prod
                             - 1
                        -->
                        <entry key="signatureUser" value="1"/>
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="dk.beboerparkering.integration.dmr.impl.agent.UTPasswordCallback"/>
                        <!-- General Configuration -->
                        <entry key="addInclusivePrefixes" value="false"/>
                        <!-- Signature Configuration -->
                        <entry key="signatureParts" value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}BinarySecurityToken"/>
                        <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
                        <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="test/etc/Client_Sign.properties"/>
                        <entry key="signatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <!--<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>-->
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>

    <!-- This part is only relevant if the client consumes the effective WSDL of the
         running web service. That is, fetches the WSDL from the running system and
         in that case we have to ignore certain polices as CXF does not have native
         handlers for these policies.
         In this sample: the wsdl is fetched locally from the resources directory.
    -->
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.IgnorablePolicyInterceptorProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <!-- the list of assertion types that can be ignored -->
            <list>
                <bean class="javax.xml.namespace.QName">
                    <constructor-arg value="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="Confidentiality"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="javax.xml.namespace.QName">
                    <constructor-arg value="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="Identity"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="javax.xml.namespace.QName">
                    <constructor-arg value="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="Integrity"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="javax.xml.namespace.QName">
                    <constructor-arg value="http://www.bea.com/wls90/security/policy"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="MessageAge"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You are using 7 schemas, but only 6 schemas are referenced in schemaLocation. Might be that your app is unable to find the actual file you are referring to.

Comment: @Tobb If that is the case then the project will not run but the only issue comes when running the JAR file. OR you can help me with which reference I need to add in schemaLocation?

Comment: The schemas are resolved from your classpath, so it might be that you are missing some dependency in the jar that is present in your development environment/IDE.